# What is the best way to get the value in xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml

my xml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="euc-kr"?>
<root>
    <params>
        <param id="ErrorCode" type="STRING">-1</param>
        <param id="ErrorMsg" type="STRING">FAIL</param>
    </params>
    <dataset id="G_HeaderCommon">
        <colinfo id="string000" size="128" type="STRING"/>
        <record>
            <string000>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string000>
        </record>
    </dataset>
    <dataset id="G_HeaderStdmsg">
        <colinfo id="std_msg_cntn" size="128" type="STRING"/>
        <colinfo id="std_msg_code" size="128" type="STRING"/>
        <record>
            <std_msg_cntn>System error occured.</std_msg_cntn> -->  I have to get this value.
            <std_msg_code>BL0012</std_msg_code>
        </record>
    </dataset>
</root>
```

And I want to get the value of "std_msg_cntn".

XPath or Linq would be fine.

I am not really good at xml stuff.

would u like to help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is trivial with XPath or LINQ to XML, and a few moments reading the documentation on MSDN will serve you well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string path = @"C:\SomePlace\XMLFile1.xml";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

var targetDataset = xDoc
    .Descendants("dataset")
    .Where(a => a.Attribute("id").Value == "G_HeaderStdmsg");

bool datasetHasStdMsgCntn = targetDataset
    .Elements("colinfo")
    .Where(a => a.Attribute("id").Value == "std_msg_cntn")
    .Any();

if (datasetHasStdMsgCntn)
{
    var targetElement = targetDataset.Descendants("std_msg_cntn").First();
    string stdMsgCntn = targetElement.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the value of element `colinfo` with `id="std_msg_cntn"`, in this particular case that node is empty.

```
    XDocument main = XDocument.Load(@"FilePath");

    var result = main.Descendants("root")
            .Descendants("dataset").Descendants("colinfo")
            .Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "std_msg_cntn")
            .Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```